# Q: chain callbacks

Tags: node.js, promise, gulp, q

I'm trying to run callbacks in specific order.

Basically I have a `gulp` task that receives an array with four CSS paths. I need minify each file and print status about progress. Something like that:

```
Minifying file AAA.css: OK
Minifying file BBB.css: OK
Minifying file CCC.css: FAIL
Minifying file DDD.css: OK
```

First I write `Minifying file AAA.css`, so I run some `gulp` methods, and `on("end")` or `on("error")` it should complete the phrase with `OK\n` or `FAIL\n`, respectively.

My problem is that it is printing somethink like:

```
Minifying file AAA.css: Minifying file BBB.css: {...} DDD.css: Finished {...}.
OK
OK
FAIL
OK
```

This is how I trying to do:

```
gulp.task("watch", function () {
    var files = [ "AAA.css", "BBB.css", "CCC.css", "DDD.css" ]; 
    var promise = Q();

    underscore.each(files, function (file) {
        minify(promise, file);
    });

    return promise;
});

function minify(promise, file) {
    promise.then(function() { write("Minifying " + file + ": ") });
    promise.then(function() {
        return gulp.src(file).{...}
            .on("error", function() { write("FAIL"); }) 
            .on("end", function() { write("OK"); }) 
    });
}
```

I tried use `Q.defer()` and create a promise for each file in loop too, but without success... Like:

```
function minify(file) {
    var promise = Q();
    promise.then(function() { write("Minifying " + file + ": ") });
    promise.then(function() {
        return gulp.src(file).{...}
            .on("error", function() { write("FAIL"); }) 
            .on("end", function() { write("OK"); }) 
    });

    return promise();
}
```

What should I do? Maybe Promise or Deferred will not solve my problem?

**Edit**: my current code is http://pastebin.com/tSaXH1iF

Comment: So you want to give up running them in parallel?

Comment: I don't care if `BBB.css` as minified before `AAA.css`, but output need be like `Min BBB: OK... Min AAA: OK...`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the usual async problem: `gulp.src()` will finish long after you've printed your "Minifying...". The solution is to wait for it to finish before printing the "Minifying..." message:

```
function minify(file) {
    var promise = Q();
    promise.then(function() {
        return gulp.src(file).{...}
            .on("error", function() { write("Minifying " + file + ":FAIL"); }) 
            .on("end", function() { write("Minifying " + file + ":OK"); }) 
    });

    return promise();
}
```

There's really no simple way around it unless you want to use some fancy terminal trickery to move the cursor to the correct line to print "OK" or "FAIL".

Comment: Consider that, initially, I want print it in order (AAA, BBB, ...). And I want tell to user that I will start minifying the CSS, and, *asyncly* tell if it is OK or FAIL. Basically: for each CSS, print building message, wait for build, print build status message, advance to next.

Comment: @DavidRodrigues: Like I said, there's no simple way to do that. That is, there is no way to do that with simple `console.log()` or `write()`. That's because prompt is already on the next line after you print the next "Minifying...". The only way to do what you want is to move the cursor to the exact coordinates in order to print the right thing. This is not trivial. Look at the terminal-control or blessed packages on npm to control the terminal (there are other libraries of course). But by this point you're basically writing a console app, way beyond what a gulp file should be.

Answer (score 0):

building on slebetman's answer, I do not think you are building promises properly( unless `gulp.src` returns promise), Your code would work but with current state the promise has no effect.

with `Q.defer` you can promisify the pipe like:

```
function minify(file) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    gulp.src(file).{...}
        .on("error", function(err) { write("Minifying " + file + ": FAIL"); deferred.reject(err);}) 
        .on("end", function() { write("Minifying " + file + ": OK");deferred.resolve(); });
    return promise();
}
```

Comment: I guess that `gulp.src` returns a stream. Stream is something different of Promise? I'll try your method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**I finally found the mistake.** Basically, `.then()` will expect a "promise factory", instead of "promise instance".

---

I was incorrectly running the function `minifyCSS()`, instead of bind it to `.then()`.

**Minify CSS function**: it was correct. I created a defer on it and return it promise.

```
var deferred = Q.defer();

gulp.src(...)
    .pipe(...)
    .on("end", ... deffered.resolve() ...);

return deferred.promise;
```

**Before:**

```
var promise = Q();

promise.then( ... start message ... );
promise.then(minifyCSS(file)); 

return promise;
```

**After:**

```
var promise = Q();

promise.then( ... start message ... );
promise.then(minifyCSS.bind(null, file)); 

return promise;
```

Note only the second `.then()` call on each example.

A small logical mistake. Gulp was executed instantly when I called `minifyCSS()` on first example (*before*), instead of execute after last `.then()` finished (like in *after*).